# Is there a easier way to execute a insert query into 2 rows?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I need this query to go into 2 rows, im currently testing and doing it this way, is there a simlified way ?

```
  mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO `private`(`id`, `time`,  `message`, `hunter`, `target`, `status`, `target_colotest ','Dispute Referee','$name','','user','sadmin','','','')");



 mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO `private`(`id`, `time`,`message`, `hunter`, `target`, `status`, `target_color`, `hunter_color`, `view`, `avatar`, `hunter_guest` )VALUES('','$time','test','Dispute Referee','$oname','','user','sadmin','','','')");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a comma-separated list of value collections to do

```
 INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3)
            VALUES('val1', 'val2', 'val3'),
                   ('val4', 'val5', 'val6'),
                   ('val7', 'val8', 'val9')
```

and get multiple rows in a single SQL statement: three rows in this example.

Comment: your example isnt showing me how to insert into 2 records

Comment: i need 2 different records to get the info in my example.

Comment: @user5420896 This shows you how to do 3 different records, not simply 2.... first record has values 'val1', 'val2', 'val3'; second record has values 'val4', 'val5', 'val6', etc